# Including LWJGL on Netbeans via Maven

Tags: maven, netbeans, lwjgl

I have a problem with including LWJGL on Netbeans via Maven 2. 
I create my own project, and I added new depency. I haven't problems with writting code, but when I try to compile and run it I always getting exception:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path**

I read some articles about this problem, because it is common problem; And I know that I should use -Djava.library.path=/native/

But...

I don't get so much Maven  and I cannot find the path, where maven stored these libraries. Maybe should I make some other things?

BTW I have not idea, why maven not linked it

Answer (score 0):

if you are running the project via exec-maven-plugin, you need to tell netbeans to include the exec.args property when running and within that property have the right -Djava.library.path=. That's done in the Actions panel in project customizer.